# Checking value types in Java editors

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, strong-typing

I new in Java Development, but have expirience in other languages. I choosen Java, because it have got strong typing, but when I started to learning simple examples i can't find simple type checking in editors. I tried Eclipse and IDEA, but in both i didn't get any warnings in this simple code

```
public class BlockTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int x;
       x = 'a';
       System.out.print(x);
    }
}
```

I tried equate int variable to string value and didn't get any warnings. Why this is not error for editors? When work in other language I always heared how usefull strong types. Why i can't see it? Or maybe checking only input and output function types? Or I should install some spacial linter or use something 'strict' mode in editor?

Comment: `char` is still an integral type. Each character is mapped to an integer value, which can be stored in an `int`.

Comment: Ouuu... I didn't think about it. Tried double or not one character and got error. Thank you for this point. Interested, how often missed such an error when checking

Comment: No problem! The behavior was inherited from C.